# What is Danny counting here?

Tags: gemini-man

In scifi cloning concept movie *Gemini Man* (2019), while Danny was searching for dupe keys for a boat,
she was attacked by a DIA agent:

> DIA Agent: You can tell me now, or you can tell me in five minutes 
>    minus your teeth. But you're gonna tell me.
>
> Danny: **I counted three**. How many did you bring?

What is Danny counting here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the official novelization](https://books.google.com/books?id=N92fDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT70&lpg=PT70&dq=gemini%20man%20%22I%20counted%20three%22&source=bl&ots=WlMSv0dhkN&sig=ACfU3U1lQDivur8DMrnSvaTPKUOzGymNRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPtOf6lJHnAhWnmOAKHVO_ADAQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=gemini%20man%20%22I%20counted%20three%22&f=false):

> .... The knife landed on the floor; at the same moment, there was a rifle shot from outside. Two more followed; then silence. The man froze, still holding onto her.
>
> "Well, I counted three," Danny said chattily, "How many guys did you bring?"

So, she's counting gunshots, implying them to correspond to the number of backup agents he brought.